# Editing large documentation topic locks up my browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I'm currently splitting an example that was created into smaller examples, but after going at this for awhile my browser locks up when interacting with the page.

The offending draft: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sitecore/1297/api?draftId=17444

The stacktrace that Firefox hangs on constantly. (This also happens in chrome)

```
StackExchange.docs.diff</</</i.prototype.extractCommon@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:1321:0
i@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:1258:0
StackExchange.docs.diff</</</i.prototype.diff@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:1303:0
i@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:1365:0
StackExchange.docs.diff</<.characters@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:1718:0
Kt@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:4666:0
Jt/e/<@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:4480:0
f</<.each@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2:11934
Jt/e@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:4466:0
Jt/<@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:4586:0
t/a@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:5263:0
f.event.dispatch@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:4298
e@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:5250:0
StackExchange.docs.topic</$a</r.editorSwitched@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:5393:0
Ct@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:3925:0
l/</</p@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:2354:0
l/</<@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:2365:0
t/a@http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=16c51cc1ede3:5263:0
```

Comment: Non repro, but try this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sitecore/drafts/17444?diffType=SideBySideMarkdown

Comment: You need to be editing the topic for it to happen. That URL just redirects me back to editing the topic.

Comment: Still can't repro, try rejecting my draft and improving it instead http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/18997

Comment: You need to move as much content as I have in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This also happened to me a few times already. Same profiling, `diff` seems problematic.